# How to show interestial ads every x minutes in Flutter but as a background Task?

Tags: flutter, admob, flutter-dependencies

My Flutter app has multiple screens like 20-25 screens. What I want is display an interestial ads every 3 minutes. I tried some approach but all was limited to single scree. But i want is have a universal 3 minutes ads displayer that i could run from main method and the ads shows avery page with the single timer.
Help Appreciated.

Comment: what's your current approach , how are you maintaining the timer

Comment: you'll have do something in `init` which calls that code after every x mintues

Comment: Its working fine on a single screen but when I navigate to other screen by pushReplacement the timer stops and no ads is seen.

Comment: You can pass the remaining time to other pages when navigating and continue count down in each screen? I am not really sure if it is a good approach but this is first thing got in my mind

Comment: You can create a global / static timer object so that it keeps running no matter what screen is displayed.